# How can I get the index of an array in a for loop in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an array of goals that the user insert on the app, that array of goals gets render in a route in vue using a v-for loop, having the name of the goal and next to it a button. Each goal is an object where I have an empty array where I want to push the todo that the user insert in the input so it gets added to the relative goal once clicked next to it. I'm using vuex so I have to transfer the index and the todo to the mutation in store.js .

**This is the route where the index value is from**

```
            <div class="list" v-for="(goal, index) in goals" :key="goal.goal">
                <h2>{{goal}}</h2><add-button-task></add-button-task>
                <div :class="{ isActiveTask : !isActiveTask }">
                <div class="modal-backdrop">
                    <div @keyup.enter="addToDo(index)" class="modal">
                        <p>Add task to {{goal.goal}}</p>
                        <h3>Task</h3>
                        <br>
                        <input  @keyup.escape="abortTask()" type="text" v-model="todo" maxlength="60">
                        <button @click="addToDo(index)">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="addLongTerm">
                <p>Create a new long term goal</p>
                <add-button-goal id="add"></add-button-goal>
            </div>

addToDo(index){
            if(this.todo == ''){
                return
            } else {
                this.$store.commit('addToDo',
                {'index':index,
                'todo': this.todo})
                this.todo = '';
                this.toggleIsActiveTask();
            }
        },
```

**This is in the vuex**

```
addToDo(state,object){
            state.goals[object.index].toDo.push(object.todo)
            console.log(object.index)
        },
```

Comment: what's the issue or what's the desired behavior?

Comment: `v-for="(goal, index) in goals"` this gives you the index, I don't see the problem

Comment: The issue is that the function is not able to get the index from the for loop, it only gets the index of the last element in the array of goals. I need to have the exact index of the goal that i'm clicking in order to add the todo to the correct goal

Comment: Try doing "() => function(index)" instead of "function(index)"

Comment: your addToDo function has 2 parameters. You should use state instead of object. State is your index.

Comment: Nope It doesn't work in that way either.

Comment: @RodTalingting How should the state recognize which element i clicked in the route if I don't give back the information from the route?